# Errors on Ubuntu 20.04 update

Tags: 20.04, package-management, software-installation, updates, update-manager

I ran a regular update of my Ubuntu 20.04 PC this morning and the following dialog popped up:

[image: software updater broken]

Per the instruction I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And it appears there were more errors.

[image]

I'm still pretty new to Linux, so this is beyond my capacity to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

> ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'typing'

Try to install absent module 'typing':

```
pip install typing
```

Then run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thanks, Apomelitos. Typing installed successfully and 'pip list' reveals that typing 3.7.4.3 is installed, however there are still errors at the end of the sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f process. Comment doesn't allow me to post a screenshot,...ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing'
dpkg: error processing package python3.9-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.9-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.9-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)